# my nginx don't response to websocket request

Tags: javascript, php, nginx, websocket, ratchet

i have plesk server with apache2 and nginx and i have a websocket app it works on port `2589` and i used `ratchet` and `autobahn` to work with websocket,
nginx version
`nginx version: nginx/1.20.2`
and ufw status
`Status: inactive`
and my nginx directive config for websocket

```
location ^~ /WsConn
{
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

    proxy_pass             http://localhost:2589;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Client-Verify SUCCESS;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_read_timeout     60;
    proxy_connect_timeout  60;
    proxy_redirect         off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

my js to connect to ws

```
new ab.Session(
        'wss://domain.com/WsConn',
        function() {
           console.log('Connected!');
        }
        function() {
            console.warn('SOCKET DISCONNECTED, WAIT NOW!!');
        }, {
            'skipSubprotocolCheck': true
        }
```

and i keep getting connection failed in my browser
[image]

btw it was works so fine on my old VPS and there was some settings inside the directive config for nginx that made it worked, but when i moved on new VPS i lost this settings, so i hope if someone can help me setup the perfect settings for it again to make it accept websocket requests.

thanks.

EDIT: i found this errors in `proxy_error.log`

```
2022/08/23 19:25:17 [error] 175835#0: *2873868 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: domain.com, request: "GET /WsConn?sessid=mrgk7rg627morchjqml982iug2&&tk=8f45d30d6899f54d8f6c54886cd00286&&uid=1&&isios=0 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:2589/WsConn?sessid=mrgk7rg627morchjqml982iug2&&tk=8f45d30d6899f54d8f6c54886cd00286&&uid=1&&isios=0", host: "www.domain.com"
2022/08/23 19:25:17 [error] 175835#0: *2873868 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: domain.com, request: "GET /WsConn?sessid=mrgk7rg627morchjqml982iug2&&tk=8f45d30d6899f54d8f6c54886cd00286&&uid=1&&isios=0 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:2589/WsConn?sessid=mrgk7rg627morchjqml982iug2&&tk=8f45d30d6899f54d8f6c54886cd00286&&uid=1&&isios=0", host: "www.domain.com"
```

Comment: Looks like your the websocket server application is denying the connection request. Check your application logs.